# Не работает ng-controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Добрый вечер. Есть такая проблема: ввожу данные, которые должны отправляться в БД на сервисе Firebase (https://firebaseio.com/). Но ничего не происходит (по нажатию на кнопку даже не видно сообщения "Test" и "Добавлено"). Как я понимаю, дело в ангуляре. Подскажите, что не так я сделал?
modal.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('boatCtrl', function($scope){
    alert('Test');
    $scope.boatSize="";
    $scope.myData = Firebase("https://boiling-inferno-4895.firebaseio.com/");
    $scope.saveBoat=function(){
        $scope.myData.push({boatSize:$scope.boatSize});
        alert('Добавлено');
    }
});
```

admin.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Администрация</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modal.js"></script>

</head>


<body style="margin:20px" ng-controller="boatCtrl">
    <div>
        <label>Размеры лодки, см</label>
        <input type="text" id="boatSize" ng-model="boatSize"><br/>

        <label>Высота лодки, см</label>
        <input type="text" id="boatHeight" ng-model="boatHeight"><br/>

        <label>Вес лодки, кг</label>
        <input type="text" id="boatWeight" ng-model="boatWeight"><br/>

        <label>Грузоподъемность, кг</label>
        <input type="text" id="boatWeight2" ng-model="boatWeight2"><br/>

        <label>Количество мест</label>
        <input type="text" id="boatPlace" ng-model="boatPlace"><br/>

        <label>Цена</label>
        <input type="text" id="boatPrice" ng-model="boatPrice"><br/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="saveBoat">
            Сохранить
        </button>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top:50px">
        Размеры лодки, см : {{boatSize}}<br/>
        Высота лодки, см : {{boatHeight}}<br/>
        Вес лодки, кг : {{boatWeight}}<br/>
        Грузоподъемность, кг : {{boatWeight2}}<br/>
        Количество мест : {{boatPlace}}<br/>
        Цена : {{boatPrice}}
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: забыли `()` -> `ng-click="saveBoat()"`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Значение указанное для атрибута `ng-click` вычисляется как expression ангуляра. Таким образом сейчас

```
ng-click="saveBoat"
```

при вычислении будет просто получена ссылка на функцию.

Для того чтобы функция была выполнена, она должна быть указана со скобками как и в обычном javascript коде

```
ng-click="saveBoat()"
```

Comment: Ты мой спаситель!